# Convert a string to multi-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, api, multidimensional-array, xmlhttprequest

This is returned by the REST API: `[[5671, 204], [5673, 192], [5674, 120], [5683, 120], [5684, 192], [5685, 204]]`

when i am doing typeof i am getting string for above in javascript . i want to convert it to a multi dimensional array.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='/hello/get_pw_status';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
var resp;

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
console.log(Http.responseText);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =Http.responseText;
console.log(typeof Http.responseText);


var pw_data = [];
pw_data=Http.data;
console.log(pw_data);
}
```

Comment: var resp = JSON.parse(Http.responseText); and use resp as your data source

Comment: it is working but in the console i can see below exception

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse to convert the array in the response string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='/hello/get_pw_status';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
var resp;

Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    var multiDimentionalArray;
    if(typeof Http.responseText == "string") {
        multiDimentionalArray = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
    }
    conosle.log(multiDimentionalArray);
}
```

Comment: Your most welcome, you can accept the answer and close the question

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Http.onreadystatechange (index:21)  it is giving me array but in console i can see above exception also , anything wrong in my code?

Comment: you can try to place the JSON.parse inside a try catch block, the error occurs when the reponse received is not a proper JS object

Comment: it could also be possible that your response string contains encoded characters, make sure there are none.